# Does influence on gravity increase with mass when velocities approach the speed of light?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, mass

In other words, when a particle's mass increases significantly as it approaches the speed of light (c), does its influence on gravity increase, and if so, does it increase proportionally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reletivistic mass as seen by different observers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29632/)

Comment: Also see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/

Answer (score 1):

The mass (the true mass) is an intrinsic property of a body, i.e, it does not depends on the observer's frame of reference. The mass used when calculating the gravitational force, via Newton's law, does not change. So in answer to your question: "No, the gravitational force doesn't change in that situation".

I strongly suggest to read this [popular article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0602037) by Lev Okun where he calls the "relativistic mass" a pedagogical virus.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a so-called relativistic mass which changes with velocity is no longer considered the best interpretation of mass in special relativity. Instead, the invariant/rest mass is used. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity) for a discussion. The increase in energy (through momentum) of energy associated with speeding up, however, does increase the extent to which an object contributes to the *stress-energy tensor* of the system under investigation. Hence, it is a stronger source of gravity.

Comment: Note that, for a single particle, the trace of the stress energy tensor is invariant under a boost, and that this is the one number you typically associate with the "source of the gravitational field," though of course, you should generically use the whole stress-energy tensor.